Infimum of a functional in a set of continous functions
The set $A$ is defined as $A=\left\{ f\in\mathcal{C^{1}}\left(\left[0,1  \right],\mathbb{R}  \right),f(0)=1 \right\}$, and we define the functional $\phi$ as $\phi(f)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$.  I'm asked to find $\underset{f\in A}{inf}\;\phi(f)$ and i have the idea of using the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=1-x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ to prove that $\underset{f\in A}{inf}\;\phi(f)=0$ but i'm not sure how to proceed.
Any ideas? 
Edit: I forgot to add the condition that every function in $A$ is non negative, so that means $A=\left\{ f\in\mathcal{C^{1}}\left(\left[0,1  \right],\mathbb{R}  \right),f(0)=1,f(x)\geq0 \right\}$

I can find an $f\in \mathcal{C}^1[0,1]$ with $f(0)=1$ and $\phi(f)=-1/2$, viz. $f(x)=1-3x$, so I’m not convinced that the infimum is $0$.

You're already most of the way there. Remember, to establish an infimum you need to prove it is

A lower bound
The largest possible lower bound

The sequence you've constructed establishes that no number larger than $0$ can be a lower bound.
But how do you know that for all $f \in A$, we have $\phi(f) \geq 0$? You still need to prove this, although given that $f \in A \implies f \geq 0$ this follows from a basic property of the integral.

Yeah, i forgot to add the condition that all f in A are non negative, let me edit
